# how to set javascript interval for once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I build a jquery carousel. But when I do fast Swiperight or left for interval will interfere and work fastly. How can I fix this?
[Here is uploaded project](http://taximerc.ir/)

I have settings variable in setting interval is time for Setinterval and items are my images, Slide is active image to show, Clock is my Setinterval Function.
when slide change I clear clock variable and after then set it with time out to user can view the slide and slide does not change.

```
var settings = $.extend({
   interval: 5000,
   element: this.selector,
   items: ['images/1.jpg','images/2.jpg','images/3.jpg'],
   slide: 0,
   clock: 0,
}, options);

// Touch
$(settings.element + ' .primary img').on("swiperight", function () {
   nextSlide();
   pauseInterval();
   setTimeout(function () {
      if (!settings.clock)
         settings.clock = setInterval(nextSlide, settings.interval)
   }, 4000);
}).on("swipeleft", function () {
   prevSlide();
   pauseInterval();
   setTimeout(function () {
      if (!settings.clock)
         settings.clock = setInterval(prevSlide, settings.interval)
   }, 4000);
});

// Next Slide
function nextSlide() {
   settings.slide++;
   if (settings.slide >= settings.items.length) settings.slide = 0;
      $(settings.element + ' .primary img').attr('src', settings.items[settings.slide]).attr('data-slide', settings.slide);
   activeThumbnail()
}

// Prev Slide
function prevSlide() {
   settings.slide--;
   if (settings.slide < 0) settings.slide = settings.items.length;
   $(settings.element + ' .primary img').attr('src', settings.items[settings.slide]).attr('data-slide', settings.slide);
   activeThumbnail()
}

//Pause Interval
function pauseInterval() {
   clearInterval(settings.clock);
   settings.clock = 0;
}
```

Comment: I do not understand... the user make a swipe so you pause the interval and then you want the interval to start again after 4 seconds? and what is not working? the restart of interval after 4 seconds or the problem is that the interval do not pause ? cause if the problem is that "the interval do not pause" is not the interval... the problem is that the setTimeout's are acumulating

Comment: use clearTimeout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will find it simpler to work with `setTimout()` exclusively instead of a mix of `setTimout()`  and `setInterval()`.

There's no unique way to write the code. Here's one :

```
var settings = $.extend({
    'delay': {
        'long_': 9000, // (4000 + 5000) after swiping 
        'short_': 5000 // auto
    },
    'element': this.selector,
    'items': ['images/1.jpg', 'images/2.jpg', 'images/3.jpg'], // array of Strings
    'slide': 0,
    'clock': null
}, options);

$(settings.element + ' .primary img').on('swiperight', nextSlide).on('swipeleft', prevSlide); // nice and simple

// nextSlide() and prevSlide() ...
// in auto: `delay` will be `settings.delay.short_`.
// on manual swipe: `delay` will be `undefined` and will default to `settings.delay.long_`.
function nextSlide(delay) {
    delay = (delay === undefined) ? settings.delay.long_ : delay;
    settings.slide = (settings.slide + 1) % settings.items.length;
    set(nextSlide, delay);
}
function prevSlide(delay) {
    delay = (delay === undefined) ? settings.delay.long_ : delay;
    settings.slide = (settings.slide + settings.items.length - 1) % settings.items.length;
    set(prevSlide, delay);
}

// set() does all the stuff common to nextSlide() and prevSlide().
function set(action, delay) {
    $(settings.element + ' .primary img').attr('src', settings.items[settings.slide]).attr('data-slide', settings.slide);
    activeThumbnail();
    clearTimeout(settings.clock); // relevant only after a manual swipe, but does no harm in auto.
    settings.clock = setTimeout(action.bind(null, settings.delay.short_), delay);
}
```

Comment: Wow! You have many skills. Is is possible to introduce an educational video to make jquery plugins? I hope to hard practice to be professionals like you get?

Comment: I test it , work fine, but when I swipe to right or left slides change twice! I upload my codes and have used your helps in this but doesn`t work carefully

Comment: My understanding is that a left/right swipe should interrupt the "auto" rotation process, then restart it after an extended delay. Is that correct?